# How to set multiple implements to RecyclerView android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I was trying to trying accomplish something like this:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> implements FastScrollRecyclerView.SectionedAdapter implements Filterable {
// All adapter related code goes here
}
```

But, the multiple `implements` is not going through as it's trigger an error **{ expected**.

Is that possible to use multiple `implements` to the same `adapter`? If yes, how?

Comment: Get rid the other implements and use comma.

Comment: `public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> implements FastScrollRecyclerView.SectionedAdapter, Filterable {
// All adapter related code goes here
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this,

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> implements FastScrollRecyclerView.SectionedAdapter, Filterable {
// All adapter related code goes here
}
```